# Change all string limit in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm with Rails 4
I've a huge database and I need to remove all the varchar size limit.

I'm using

```
change_column :table, :column, :string, :limit => nil
```

And it's working well.

But it is possible, from the migration, to make automatically this operation for all the string fields of the database, in a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
models = ["User", "Item"]

models.each do |model|

  model.columns.each do |col|
    if col.type == :string
      change_column eval(model).table_name.to_sym , col.name.to_sym, :string, :limit => nil
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I edited to give you an example. It can run as a single migration

Comment: I don't think a need to add/remove anything. Just a change_column will be ok. My problem is the database is realy huge and I wanted to automate the process for all the string field.

Comment: ok, so you could do Model.columns.each and look for :string type

Comment: You can use Model.table_name to get the name of the table.

Comment: I edited the answer with a possible solution ... didnt test it

Comment: Finally, you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.each` to avoid specifying all the models manually.